What should I use to fill the gap between asphalt driveway and concrete-encased channel drain?
I'm planning to excavate and install 26 ft of channel drain (NDS 5" Pro Series) in front of my garage, connected to my asphalt driveway.

Installation instructions specify to create a concrete form that is 4" in front of (on both sides) and below the 5.5"W x 5.5"H channel drain.
Once the concrete dries, the form is removed. But won't there be a gap on both sides of the concrete channel drain?
What should be used to fill the gap on the side of the drain that meets with the garage floor?
What should be used to fill the gap on the side that meets the asphalt driveway?
Should I use concrete bonding adhesive so that the drain's concrete sticks to the garage floor's concrete?
NDS drain install video

Cold- pack asphalt patching compound?

You don't put wood along the concrete edge of the garage. The form is a big flat U, as shown in the blue lines in the pic.


Right.  You're gonna sawcut along RMD's blue lines.  That, plus the existing concrete garage threshold will basically be the edge of your "form" (which will stay in place) and the concrete will go right up to the edge.
